# Laravel GraphQL Lighthouse unit testing mutation returns error "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>"

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am working on a Laravel project. I am developing an API using GraphQL Lighthouse. I am writing the unit tests for my application where it involves file upload feature. But it is throwing error.

This is my mutation code:

```
class CreateMenuItem
{
    public function __invoke($_, array $args)
    {
        //create menu item and returns

        return $menuItem;
    }
}
```

I have a schema for the mutation as follows:

```
input CreateMenuItemInput {
    image: Upload
    name: String
    price: Float
    menu_item_option_name: [String]
    menu_item_option_price: [Float]
    menu_item_extra_name: [String]
    menu_item_extra_price: [Float]
}

extend type Mutation @middleware(checks: ["auth:api", "auth.restaurant-admin"]) {
    createMenuItem(input: CreateMenuItemInput): MenuItem! @createMenuItemValidation
}
```

This is my validation directive:

```
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives\ValidationDirective;

class CreateMenuItemValidationDirective extends ValidationDirective
{
    public function name()
    {
        return 'createMenuItemValidation';
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'input.name' => [ 'required' ],
            'input.price' => [ 'required', 'numeric' ],
            'input.menu_item_option_name' => [ 'required', 'array' ],
            'input.menu_item_option_price' => [ 'required', 'array' ],
            'input.menu_item_extra_name' => [ 'required', 'array' ],
            'input.menu_item_extra_price' => [ 'required', 'array' ],
        ];
    }
}
```

I can create the menu item from the GraphQL playground. But when I write the test for it, it is failing. This is my test:

```
class CreateMenuItemTest extends RestaurantAdminTestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function creating_menu_item_create_menu_if_not_exists()
    {
        Passport::actingAs($this->restaurantAdmin);
        $imageFile = UploadedFile::fake()->create('image.jpg', 500);
        $this->multipartGraphQL(
            [
                'operations' =>
                    '
                    {
                        "query": "mutation Upload($image: Upload) { createMenuItem(input: { image: $image, name: "testing", price: 12, menu_item_option_name:[ "testing 1", "testing 2" ], menu_item_option_price:[ 11, 12 ], menu_item_extra_name:[ "testing 1", "testing 2" ], menu_item_extra_price:[ 12, 13 ] }) { id } }",
                        "variables": {
                            "image": null
                        }
                    }
                    ',
                'map' =>
                    '
                    {
                        "0": ["variables.image"]
                    }
                    '
            ],
            [
                '0' => $imageFile
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

It is not even hitting the mutation. I get the following response.

```
[{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>",
            "extensions": {
                "category": "graphql"
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}].
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$imageFile = UploadedFile::fake()->create('image.jpg', 500);
$response = $this->multipartGraphQL(
    [
        'operations' => json_encode(
        [
            'query' => /** @lang graphql*/
'"mutation Upload($image: Upload) { createMenuItem(input: { image: $image, name: \\"testing\\", price: 12, menu_item_option_name:[ \\"testing 1\\", \\"testing 2\\" ], menu_item_option_price:[ 11, 12 ], menu_item_extra_name:[ \\"testing 1\\", \\"testing 2\\" ], menu_item_extra_price:[ 12, 13 ] }) { id } }",
                "variables": {
                    "image": null
                }'
        ]),
        'map' =>'{"0": ["variables.image"]}'
    ],
    [
        '0' => $imageFile
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your request is failing is because your JSON is invalid in `operations`.

Inside your `query` key in the json, you have a bunch of `"`, however you have to escape them. This is because it's JSON.

A great idea is to add phpdoc lang tags, this way IDE's can help you to show that your JSON is invalid.

So your query fixed will look the following way

```php
$imageFile = UploadedFile::fake()->create('image.jpg', 500);
$response = $this->multipartGraphQL(
    [
        'operations' => /** @lang JSON */
            '
            {
                "query": "mutation Upload($image: Upload) { createMenuItem(input: { image: $image, name: \\"testing\\", price: 12, menu_item_option_name:[ \\"testing 1\\", \\"testing 2\\" ], menu_item_option_price:[ 11, 12 ], menu_item_extra_name:[ \\"testing 1\\", \\"testing 2\\" ], menu_item_extra_price:[ 12, 13 ] }) { id } }",
                "variables": {
                    "image": null
                }
            }
            ',
        'map' => /** @lang JSON */
            '
            {
                "0": ["variables.image"]
            }
            '
    ],
    [
        '0' => $imageFile
    ]
);
```